# Why isn't OnCollisionEnter being called?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, physics

I have a hammer and an object to be hit in my scene. I put this line 
`Debug.Log("Collided with" + collision.gameObject.name);`
to debug whether the function OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision), was being called. On my hammer, there is a box collider (not trigger), and on the object to collide, it has a rigidbody (non-kinematic), and a mesh collider (convex). I've tried with various objects but it won't call oncollisionenter. They're all the same tag and layer. I made the box collider way bigger and it pushes me back when I try running into an object so it is colliding, but not calling oncollisionenter.

I've heard that it won't work with dynamically instantiated objects, and my player is instantiated at runtime. Could that be it, and are there any fixes? EDIT: I tried disabling the script that instantiates the player (with the hammer on them), and then just having the player in the scene. and it still doesn't recognise any collision from oncollisionenter

Comment: A couple things to check: is the method signature spelled correctly? (This might sound trivial, but we get a question every couple months where this is the culprit) Was your object with a Rigidbody unmoving and put to sleep by the physics engine before your object without a Rigidbody moved into it? (The physics engine will only check collisions where there's at least one non-sleeping body involved, since it assumes colliders with no bodies won't move. if you're moving a collider, it should have a body)

Comment: Are you perhaps using 2D colliders and 2D rigidbodies? In that case you have to use the function `OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D)`.

Comment: @Philipp nope it's definitely 3d

Comment: @DMGregory yep it's spelled correctly. I don't think it's sleeping, other things can collide with it, just not my hammer. I haven't touched anything to do with Sleep that would be default

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. Let's go through an object that can collide with your mesh versus your hammer that cannot, and identify everything that's different between the two objects / how you move them. That should help narrow down the source of the problem.

Comment: my other objects are projectiles that are being fired out of a gun. They have a box collider and a non kinematic rigidbody. but if I add a rigidbody to the hammer it spins crazily around me. It shouldn't need a rigidbody though if what it's hitting has one though?